# GStreamer and Youtube Problem RTMPSink can not write to resource

Tags: youtube, rtmp, gstreamer-1.0, java-gstreamer

I have problem with sending video to youtube using GStreamer.
My pipeline is:

```
"appsrc name=videoAppSrc ! rawvideoparse name=videoparser use-sink-caps=false format=8 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, fromat=YUV, width="+videoWidth+", height="+videoHeight+", framerate=25/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc key-int-max=60 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux ! rtmpsink name=dest location="+this.url+"/"+this.key+" t. ! queue ! matroskamux name=filemux ! filesink name=fileout location="+archFile.getAbsolutePath()+" appsrc name=audioAppSrc ! rawaudioparse use-sink-caps=true ! audioconvert ! volume name=audiovolume volume=1 ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! tee name=ta ta. ! queue ! mux. ta. ! queue ! filemux."
```

I'm using Java with gst1-java-core to push frames into the pipeline.

After some time I'm getting this kinde of error: Could not write to resource from GstRTMPSink element.
Sometimes it happends after 1 hour, sometimes after 3 hours.
I think the problem is youtube won't receive my stream.
Am I right?
Is something wrong with my pipeline?
Maybe i have to adjust some properties to get this working with youtube propably?

Comment: You're using filesink, which writes to a local file? Couldn't it just be because you're running out of disk space after a while?

Comment: @nielsdg I'm 100% sure there is not the case.
Because i have 1TB of free space on this disk where i'm writing to.